# Javascript and JQuery Dom Global Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with scope of the variable in the code

```
var ButtonPressed; //global SCOPE
$(document).ready(function()
{

  function messageAlert()
  {
    $('#buttons').append('<input type="button" id="btn" value="Clickme" />');
    return false;
  }

  messageAlert();

  $('#btn').on("click", function()
  {
    ButtonPressed = 1;
  });
}); //end document

//// UNDEFINED NOT WORKING
if (ButtonPressed === 1)
{
  alert(ButtonPressed);
}
```

I try everything about scope tutorials but I can't show variable `ButtonPressed=1` GLOBAL.

Any help ?

Comment: Is that `if` statement actually located after the `$(document).ready()` statement? In this case it will never show the alert, as this code will always be run before the button is actually clicked.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: just assign default value to ButtonPressed variable like: `var ButtonPressed = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You are binding a click event to the button `#btn` to set the global variable `ButtonPressed` which will not be fired unless you click the button.

When your code executes and reaches the block (which is in the global scope) knowing that the button have not been clicked

```
if (ButtonPressed === 1)
{
  alert(ButtonPressed);
}
```

The variable `ButtonPressed` will not be set because you haven't clicked the button so it will not alert any message.

In other words, the if statement runs before the click handler

Answer (score 0):

Explaining your code. the execution goes this way ( 1 ) --> ( 2 ) --> ( 3 )

```
    var ButtonPressed; // executed as soon as the script tag is hit -- ( 1 )

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     //......          //executed ONLY AFTER the DOM is ready - (3 )
    }); 


    if (ButtonPressed === 1) //executed as soon as the script tag is hit - ( 2 )
    { 
      alert(ButtonPressed);
    }
```

as the comments indicate, the `var ButtonPressed` is executed first, then the execution skips to the `if` check . Only after the DOM is completely ready then your code block inside the `$(document).ready` will execute.

So that means all the global scope code stuff will get executed first and then the one's inside the document ready

---

**1)** If your intention is to **Show a alert when ever a button is clicked** then do this

```
$('#btn').on("click", function()
  {
    ButtonPressed = 1;
    alert(ButtonPressed);
    // do all the stuff that should happen when a button is clicked
  });
```

---

**2)** Else if your intention is to **Check if a button was clicked??** then you can make use of the `setInterval`. using this you can check if a button was clicked or not for every say 1 secs. Like below.

```
var checkButtonStatus = setInterval(function(){
                 if (ButtonPressed === 1)
                 { 
                  alert(ButtonPressed);
                  //do all your stuff as the button was clicked
                  clearInterval(checkButtonStatus ); // remove interval as you don't need to check again.
                 }

                }, 1000);
```

**Note:** **`I would say option 2 is not efficient way of doing it, Go for option 1`**

Comment: How is this different to what KAD has explained in his answer?

Comment: The way its being explained, I donot think a newbie will be able to understand better with KAD's answer, It sounds little high level. So I am explaining as low as possible